# Show svg or image from network depending on type flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi I'm using a service that send me images, sometimes png or jpeg images and I use the flutter widget `Image`. In the other hand sometimes send me svg images intuit case I can use `flutter_svg` package, but I don't know how to switch between that widgets depending on the image type.

There isn't nothing on the url that I can use to determine the image type.

How I can do that?

UPDATE: Example response from the server, the image is on property lexeme_image

```
{
  "has_tts": true,
  "word": "one",
  "language_information": {},
  "from_language_name": "Spanish",
  "tts": "https://d1vq87e9lcf771.cloudfront.net/joeyn/b53723d682be1114be1cefce3ddbb908",
  "infinitive": null,
  "learning_language": "en",
  "translations": "un, una, uno",
  "learning_language_name": "English",
  "pos": "Numeral",
  "lexeme_image": "https://d2pur3iezf4d1j.cloudfront.net/images/4be10d03a4c6ac4078b6be0df2eb5247",
  "from_language": "es",
  "is_generic": false,
  "lexeme_id": "dd0309fb9cf34f8a2b2e029889c26ec5",
  "related_lexemes": [],
  "canonical_path": "/dictionary/English/one/d3a447831e3322e78309fa3a161c0ebf"
}
```

Comment: What data type are you receiving from the "service"? Could you elaborate and maybe show some code for that retrieval?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I update the question with an example of the server response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the `.network` constructors provided by the `Image` widgets, retrieve the Image *file* with a network request like below:

```
HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(STRING URL HERE))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) => 
        response.pipe(File('foo').openWrite()));
```

or a better example using `await`:

```
HttpClientRequest request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(STRING URL HERE));
HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

File file = File('foo');
await response.pipe(file .openWrite());
```

Then using the `image library`'s `PngDecoder` and `JpegDecoder` decoder classes `isValidFile` method, you can check if the image is a png or jpeg. Example:

```
PngDecoder png = PngDecoder();
JpegDecoder jpg = JpegDecoder();

if(png.isValidFile(file) || jpg.isValidFile(file)) {
  //use `Image.file(file)`
}
else {
  //use `SvgPicture.file(file)`
}
```

If it is either of those, you can pass the file you retrieved to the `Image.file` constructor. If it's not then use the `SvgPicture.file` constructor.

Comment: Returns error *"Cannot open file, path = 'foo' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)"*

Comment: @Alex The file name 'foo' is just a placeholder for a real file name. Use the normal methods of obtaining application storage paths e.g. [`path_provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

Comment: But if you only want to display the image, wouldn't it be redundant to write it to the file system?

Comment: @Alex Yes it would

Answer (score 3):

I found a pretty neat work-around for this and this is working fine for me.Hope that it helps you guys as well.

First use the `flutter_svg` package

Now i am assuming that you're getting the image extension as `.svg` or other image extensions like `.jpg` , `.jpg` etc.

Now i would recommend you to use `Image.network` and pass the `SvgPicture` widget in the `errorBuilder` property of `Image.network`

Here's an example for the same.

```
return Image.network(
    cryptoCoins[index]['logo_url'], //extensions like .jpg, .png etc
    height: 90,
    errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>
    SvgPicture.network(
    cryptoCoins[index]['logo_url'], // for .svg extension
    height: 90,
       ),
     );
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and wrote a little wrapper around svgpicture and the other image widgets: https://pub.dev/packages/hybrid_image

Comment: I looked at this package. Thanks @Stijn2210 for making it! Unfortunately, you have to have the file extension in the asset/network path or this package will not work. 

As shown in OP's example, the image URL does not include an extension. I have the identical issue: you have to resolve URL and look at content-type header to know if you're dealing with an SVG or PNG/JPG/GIF/etc

Comment: Ah, that might be something to work on :-) thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Stijn2210 i'd like to suggest to add an errorBuilder callback when SVG is fetched from network and has error